# AmazonError: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect to aws server and I am getting this error from dynamo DB connect.

The code is like this.

```
vuaws.dbclient().getItem('users', usrname, opts, function(err, data) {
      if (err || !data) {
        vulog.error('ddb: error in finding user \n',err);
      } else {
        vulog.debug('user got from db: ');
```

DB client is a function which is like this.

```
  dbclient: function() {
    return dynode;
  },
```

param is this.

```
users admin@gmail.com { ConsistentRead: true,
  AttributesToGet: [ 'role', 'password' ] }
```

The full bug which I am receiving is like this.

```
{ AmazonError: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/evbooth/Desktop/hirekwick/node_modules/dynode/lib/dynode/request.js:57:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
  type: 'InvalidSignatureException',
  serviceName: 'com.amazon.coral.service',
  message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.',
  statusCode: 400,
  action: 'GetItem',
  retry: [Getter] }
```

in vuaws.js dynamodb is defined in at this way.

```
  dynode.auth(vuconst.dynodeauth);
    vulog.info('dynode.attached');
    var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    vulog.info('dynamodb connected:');
```

> vuconst.dynodeauth

is like this.

```
dynodeauth: {
    "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "secretAccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "region": "us-west-2"
  },
```

Any help?

Comment: So....have you checked the key and the signing method?

Comment: @James yeah i have created the keys without + or / then i have cross-checked the server time as well

Comment: Ok, can you show how you are configuring `vuaws`?

Comment: @James question is editted

Comment: that's it? You don't pass any credentials or anything anywhere else?

Comment: @James i have updated the question

Comment: You need to configure your AWS.Config credentials.

Comment: @Hitobat I have done it which is defined in ` vuconst.dynodeauth` variable

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once when I was using other credentials in aws-cli and other in my program. Simply log out from aws-cli.

Comment: I don't know how to log out from the aws cli i made a little google and found this document which is like this. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=148833 so I created a blank login hopes its logged out?